# Hints are timing out in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, datastax

We are seeing lot of hints timing out and I don't see any thing is logs about nodes are going DOWN. This is strange to me why cassandra is building up the hints table if it does not think it is down. I don't see any GC pauses as well.

Can someone help me how to solve this problem

```
INFO [HintedHandoff:2] 2015-03-11 01:56:00,958 HintedHandOffManager.java (line 469) Timed out replaying hints to /1.1.1.79; aborting (0 delivered)
INFO [HintedHandoff:1] 2015-03-11 02:03:54,914 HintedHandOffManager.java (line 469) Timed out replaying hints to /1.1.1.76; aborting (0 delivered)
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have hints on that node indicates that the node itself is up. What this log say is that nodes 1.1.1.79 & 1.1.1.76 are down, or more likely, flapping. You should check for their statuses. Run nodetool tpstats on these nodes, if they are up, look for any dropped mutations. Inspect the logs.

Comment: I checked all the logs in 79 and 76. Everything looks fine and tpstats shows there are zero dropped mutations.

Comment: Did the handoff finish the process before you looked at these nodes? Are there any related messages in the log?

Comment: I can see this node is started hints logs and timeout. I cannot understand why it is storing hints if the gossip does not think these nodes are DOWN?

Comment: Well you can see that the hints handoff is timing out at least periodically. This clearly indicates that a connectivity issue does exist between this and 2 other nodes. You should probably inspect the logs more thoroughly.

Comment: This is happening only at specific times. If this is a network issue we should experience this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to somehow replicate that behaviour just unplug for 5 seconds, each 10 seconds, 10 times in a row the internet cable from a machine.

Here i have some extras from another machine`s /var/log/cassandra/system.log

`INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2016-10-27 14:20:00,333 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Timed out replaying hints to /192.168.0.178; aborting (0 delivered)
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2016-10-27 14:26:13,393 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: fa16996c-722c-458b-a621-eb53efa79fb2 with IP: /192.168.0.178
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2016-10-27 14:28:27,959 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Timed out replaying hints to /192.168.0.178; aborting (28850 delivered)
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2016-10-27 14:36:17,398 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: fa16996c-722c-458b-a621-eb53efa79fb2 with IP: /192.168.0.178`

I understand that sometimes it timeouts before the actual stream starts

```
aborting (0 delivered)
```

Sometimes it aborts after the stream started, specifying how many were sent and set something like a marker to know from where to stream next time :

```
aborting (28850 delivered)
```